# Pass a variable to a cmd.exe command in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, cmd, command-line, expression, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to write a powershell script that will sign on to a server remotely and run a cmd.exe expression, but I want to pass user entered variables to the cmd.exe expression. I'm a bit of a novice in powershell, mostly have learned via google fu, so it's hopefully something simple I'm missing. See script below:

```
$cred = read-host "Enter Username" - AsString
$pass = read-host "Enter Password" -AsSecureString
$startdate = read-host "Enter Start Date" -AsString
$enddate = read-host "Enter End Date" -AsString
cmd.exe /c "C:\users\mfinch\desktop\tms\repgen.exe name=mappayman user=$cred pass=$pass 
printmode=export selectall=y startdate=[$startdate] enddate=[$enddate] auto=c"
```

This is a reporting software I use that has command line parameters for scripting so I'm trying to pass the start date and end date desired so it will run everything without the user needing a sign on for the server (I have that bit worked out already).

Comment: Hi Hunter, can you please update your question with details on what exactly is going wrong? e.g. are you seeing any error messages, or does it just apper to hang etc ?

Comment: Try using `saps cmd.exe -argumentlist "/c", "C:\users\mfinch\desktop\tms\repgen.exe", "name=mappayman", "user=$cred", "pass=$pass", 
"printmode=export", "selectall=y", "startdate=[$startdate]", "enddate=[$enddate]", "auto=c"`

Comment: @Bassie running it the way written above causes it to hang. I'm assuming it launches the application but since the variables aren't passing the dates the application doesn't actually run the report.

Comment: @NekoMusume That looked like it ran successfully but I check the target and it didn't export

Comment: @HunterGiesler Please confirm what exactly you are passing into $enddate and $stardate inputs - is it possible that its not happy with the format?

Comment: @Bassie I am using "mm/dd/yyyy", which is how I would write it if I were to write a hardcoded .bat script like I was using, which looked like this:
    C:\users\mfinch\desktop\tms\repgen.exe name=mappayman user=test pass=pass 
    printmode=export selectall=y startdate=05/10/2020 enddate=05/16/2020 auto=c

Comment: If that's how you'd write it hardcoded, why did you surround both `$startdate` and `$enddate` in brackets? Did you try @NekoMusume's suggestion with those brackets removed?

Comment: Also, are you sure that you need this to run in `cmd.exe`? Your executable is likely to work just as well directly in `powershell.exe` e.g. `Start-Process -FilePath "C:\users\mfinch\desktop\tms\repgen.exe" -ArgumentList "name=mappayman", "user=$cred", "pass=$pass", "printmode=export", "selectall=y", "startdate=$startdate", "enddate=$enddate", "auto=c"`. You may, depending upon your circumstances, also need to use the `-WorkingDirectory` option. To find out how to use the command, and its options, type `Get-Help Start-Process -Full`, at the PowerShell Prompt, and press the 'ENTER' key.

Comment: Hi All,

Turns out it wasn't an issue of PowerShell passing the variable, but rather that the software version I was using was bugged and didn't except the startdate/enddate parameters. Time for a patch, yay. Thanks everyone!

Comment: @HunterGiesler your question becomes off-topic since your last comment. Please [delete it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question).

Answer (score 2):

When passing arguments to cmd from powershell, you should pass each argument 1 by 1. Like discussed in the comments of your question, the proper syntax with the scenario you provided would be:

```
saps cmd.exe -argumentlist "/c", "C:\users\mfinch\desktop\tms\repgen.exe", "name=mappayman", "user=$cred", "pass=$pass", "printmode=export", "selectall=y", "startdate=[$startdate]", "enddate=[$enddate]", "auto=c"
```

and since this doesn't work, you probably have improper syntax with passing the argument to the file so like again, the comments, you should remove the brackets (`[]`). Your code would then be:

```
saps cmd.exe -argumentlist "/c", "C:\users\mfinch\desktop\tms\repgen.exe", "name=mappayman", "user=$cred", "pass=$pass", "printmode=export", "selectall=y", "startdate=$startdate", "enddate=$enddate", "auto=c"
```

However, there is another syntax error in your code. When you read the `$pass` variable, you read it as a secure string which then encrypts the password value. You first need to decrypt it before passing it as an argument with:

```
$pass = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pass)
$pass = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($pass)
```

Which would then pass the actual input instead of the encrypted version which would've outputted:

```
System.Security.SecureString
```

when echoing out the `$pass` variable. Both commands are necessary for decryption since without the second one, the output of pass would've been a bunch of random numbers.

So in all, your code would be:

```
$cred = read-host "Enter Username" - AsString
$pass = read-host "Enter Password" -AsSecureString
$startdate = read-host "Enter Start Date" -AsString
$enddate = read-host "Enter End Date" -AsString
$pass = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pass)
$pass = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($pass)
saps cmd.exe -argumentlist "/c", "C:\users\mfinch\desktop\tms\repgen.exe", "name=mappayman", "user=$cred", "pass=$pass", "printmode=export", "selectall=y", "startdate=$startdate", "enddate=$enddate", "auto=c"
```

and if the password was the error, you could put the brackets back in.